# I'm stuck with Windows Defender security settings even if I'm PC admin

Tags: security, windows-11

To help my IT admin, I joined a lot of my Windows machine to Azure AD where my company set its domain.
To be precise the join has been done with this option:
[image: The join to Azure AD]

When the test finished I removed the join and a bad surprise came out: the MS Defender settings now belonged to my company, precisely to my company administrator.
I'm speaking of Real-time protection, Cloud-delivered protection, Automatic sample submission, and Tamper protection.

After some attempts I successfully resolve the problem of Real-time protection and Cloud-delivered protection that now are again under my control.
To be useful for others, I successfully regain control using Edit group policy this way:

- for Cloud-delivered protection, go to "Computer
  configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft
  Defender Antivirus\MAPS" and Enable "Configure local setting override
  for reporting to Microsoft MAPS"
- for Real-time protection, go to "Computer
  configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft
  Defender Antivirus\Real-time protection" and Enable all the entries
  starting with "Configure local..."

Ok 50% of work has been done but now the situation is this:
[image: The security situation of my PC]

I want to recover control on "Automatic sample submission" and "Tamper protection" and I'm not able to find out how. Is there someone who know how it could be done?

My system is installed with Windows 11 22h2 (build 22621.1848)

Comment: A screenshot of `Settings -> Email & Accounts` would be helpful. I assume you ran `DSRegCmd /Leave`?

Comment: @Ramhound 
The Settings -> Email & Accounts is empty. 
I don't know the equivalent command but I used the Windows GUI available at Settings -> Other users to remove the previous account that was located under Work or School users group.

Comment: But did you run *DSRegCmd /Leave*?

Comment: Thank you! I posted the full resolution as an answer to my own request.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the Ramhound hint I tested the situation with `DSRegCmd /Status` and found the PC was still joined to AzureAD:

[image: Status]

It's really strange I can use the Windows GUI to join the PC but it becomes useless in the opposite direction and I need to use CLI.
Worst, the GUI seems to work because it succeeded in removing the user, but indeed doesn't work at all with the AzureAD leaving.

Anyway I launched the `DSRegCmd /leave` command and the situation finally changed:
[image: Status after DSRegCmd /leave command]

The security options needed an OS restart but now everything is working again.
Thanks.